# iptables: Allowing some ports to be forwarded to the Internet

Tags: iptables

This is our network:

```
WAN <--> Router <--192.168.2.X--> [(eth0) firewall (eth1)] <--192.168.0.X--> LAN
```

We need to block access from our LAN clients to everything on the Internet **except** to some ports like SMTP, IMAP and POP. I've tried the rules below but I can't connect to any of the ports that we want to be allowed.

```
iptables -F
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport smtp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport pop3 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport imap -j ACCEPT

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

With these rules, the following test fails:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
```

If I flush the rules, the test above succeeds.

Is there something wrong with my rules? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your network require `MASQUERADE`ing?  Leave everything the same, minus the MASQERADE.

Comment: Try adding a `iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG` and check what's being droped.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. See the answer below, @Mehdi found the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the configuration of DNS? If DNS is in outside zone, you need to open DNS query ports (53-udp and tcp)

Comment: Oopsy. You're right, thanks! The client was unable to resolve the hostname. The following lines solved the problem:

    iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT